# regarding shape values in convolutional layer of CIFAR10 example

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

In the `CIFAR10` example, the `conv2` is defined as follows. How to know that the `shape=[5,5,64,64]` in kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay   should be given those values, e.g., `5,5,64,64`  In addition, in `biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))`, shape is also defined as `[64]`, how to get those values?

```
# conv2
with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
   kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                     shape=[5, 5, 64, 64],
                                     stddev=5e-2,
                                     wd=0.0)
   conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
   biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
   bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
   conv2 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
   _activation_summary(conv2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py), we see that a call to `_variable_with_weight_decay` boils down to a [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#how-does-variable-scope-work) call. We are retrieving a weight tensor (creating one if it doesn't already exist)

In a Convolutional Neural Network, the weight tensor defines a mapping from one layer to the next, but differs from a vanilla NN. The convolution implies you are applying a convolutional filter to your as you map from one layer to the next. This filter is defined with hyper-parameters which are the ones fed into `shape`.

There are four parameters fed into `shape`, the first two relate to the size of the convolution filter. In this case we  have a 5x5 filter. The third parameter defines the input dimension, which in this case is the same as the output of in the previous convolution:

```
kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                     shape=[5, 5, 3, 64],
                                     stddev=5e-2,
                                     wd=0.0)
```

The fourth parameter defines the output dimension of the tensor.

Bias is a perturbation to system used for better learning. The bias is added to the output of the convolution. Given by basic linear algebra rules, these two vectors should be of the same size, in this case it is `64`

Cheers!